# GitHub for Windows is showing old README text

Tags: github-for-windows

There is a panel on the right that is supposed to show current content of README.MD. However, I noticed that after changing the content of REAMDE.MD is hasn't updated the text in the panel. Is there a way to forcefully refresh it?

The version of GitHub for Windows I have is 1.0.41.2 (fd3fd236ac85e622194e88f248576b9fe25d28d4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, sorry about that. It's a bug and we're working on it. It's currently cached for 30 minutes and sometimes it doesn't expire when it should.

The only way to force a refresh currently is to either delete the entire folder at `%LocalAppData%\GitHub\BlobCache.api.github.com` or to locate the file in that folder that holds the README content (by looking for keywords that would appear in the README for example) and deleting that.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I've done it exactly the same way you suggested. Looking forward to a new version.

Comment: So, (as of 2013-10-17) I guess this is STILL a bug. Still not seeing readme.md

Comment: @sleeper Did you try clearing the cache? If that doesn't work please get in touch with us at support@github.com!

Comment: Using the above path I do not have the file BlobCache.api.github.com. Instead I see two files. 1] api.github.com.cache and 2] cache

Comment: Same issue with @sleeper here

Comment: @MarkusOlsson Same here (running v1.2.3.0). If this problem keeps appearing, it would be VERY USEFUL to have a "clear cache" option in the settings page.

Comment: Having same issue as @sleeper with `v1.3.3.1 0f9c06f` (on Windows 7). Deleting `api.github.com.cache.db` in `%LocalAppData%\GitHub\` seems to have fixed the problem (for now).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick search in the \AppData\Local\GitHub folder I found that the old value from README.MD is stored in one of the files in the BlobCache.api.github.com. Deleting the whole folder and restarting the app solved the issue.

Still wondering if there is a proper way for doing that from UI? Shouldn't it happen automatically anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This came from GitHub staff. It tells you how to clear the cache.

> **WARNING**: This will remove GH4W's references to your local repositories
>   and your logged-in account. You will have to log in again and let GH4W
>   re-scan your computer for repositories.

There's a known bug where we cache the 'NO README' view if you add a README after adding the repository to GitHub for Windows.

If you'd like to try to get the README to show up, you can delete the cache:

Here are the steps you will need to follow to delete the cache:

1. Close GitHub for Windows
2. Open the Git Shell
3. Run 'github —delete-cache' to clear our the GitHub for Windows cache
4. Restart GitHub for Windows — you will need to log in and add your repositories again

Comment: DO NOT use that if you don't want to loose all your settings, session and the references to your local repositories. I tried it, and I regret :(.

Comment: No local repos get lost, you only need to Drag'n'Drop them again into GitHub for Windows.