# Windows GitHub app not detecting README

Tags: windows, github, local

I published my `README.md` via the GitHub website but when I try to sync all my local repos, it doesn't seem to detect the `README.md` file. However, it does download it to the local folder and is viewable within Windows explorer.

Comment: Can you point us to the GitHub repo?

Comment: https://github.com/KyleMaclean/solar-system lol don't hate my nooby code

Comment: Not sure what your question actually is. Are you saying the readme doesn't get downloaded to your local copy?

Comment: I'm saying that in the windows application, there's a side panel that's supposed to display the readme, but I get a message saying "This repository doesn't have a readme"

Comment: Aha, getting closer. What windows application? TortoiseGit? GitExt? Official GitHub software?

Comment: The official Windows GitHub application with the "windows metro-ish" user interface

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered this exact problem and was able to fix it.

It seems like our problem is caused by the same known issue that causes this one: [GitHub for Windows is showing old README text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049744/github-for-windows-is-showing-old-readme-text).

The response there was

> Yeah, sorry about that. It's a bug and we're working on it. It's currently cached for 30 minutes and sometimes it doesn't expire when it should.
>
> The only way to force a refresh currently is to either delete the entire folder at `%LocalAppData%\GitHub\BlobCache.api.github.com` or to locate the file in that folder that holds the README content (by looking for keywords that would appear in the README for example) and deleting that.

To fix our issue, I deleted the cache content at `User\AppData\Local\GitHub`. I then restarted the official native Windows 8 GitHub application. The current readme text showed (and the warning that I had "no readme" disappeared).